# The prince rode at the head of his regiment. (was heading for the front place or already being in the front place?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, interpretation

> The prince rode at the head of his regiment.

The prince was heading for the front place or already was in the front place?

One dictionary says 'ride at' means 'drive a horse somewhere'.

Comment: He was riding [along] _at the head_ [in front] of the regiment. Yes, to _ride at_ something can mean to urge your horse towards it, but that is not the sense used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The prince rode [at the head [of his regiment]].

He was in front of his regiment, his army followed him.

[image]